# How to force an AJAX animation to wait until a click event?

Tags: ajax, events, tabs, click

I'm trying edit this AJAX code, but I don't have any previous experience with AJAX. 
The code looks for the ID #tabvanilla and displays its tabs.
this is the [source](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/create-a-tabbed-interface-using-jquery/) of the tutorial I was following.

`$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tabvanilla > ul' ).tabs({ fx: { height: 'toggle', opacity: 'toggle'} }); 
});`

The problem is that it displays by default the first TAB, and I want to wait until an event.
I already try by using a setter, but it didn't work.

My best attempt is this one, but after I select -1, it is imposible to make visible the tabs again.

```
$( '#tabvanilla > ul' ).tabs({ selected: -1  });
```

Comment: What should the initial look be? all tabs closed? or the tabs should be hidden? What event are you waiting for to finish before opening the first tab?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#tabvanilla > ul').tabs({ selected: null });
```

or from the plugin example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tabvanilla > ul').tabs({ fx: { height: 'toggle', opacity: 'toggle' }, selected: null });
    $('#featuredvid > ul').tabs();
});
```